# jQuery: Change left click to a right click

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to change a left click to a right click for a click in a defined area?

Some code:

```js
$("#my_area").click(function() {
  alert("Right click should be fired.");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_area"></div>
```

I saw that someone used `$('#element').triggerHandler('contextmenu');` for it, but it doesn't work.

Would be thankful for help!

Comment: @HenryDev I just tried the accepted answer and it didn't work. Another answer there is `.triggerHandler("contextmenu")`, which the OP said doesn't work (and also fails in my tests).

Comment: @HenryDev Unfortunately, no. Apparently something has changed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @quantumPuter That's the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857564/right-click-does-not-work-as-expected-with-panzoom

Answer (score 0):

You can't and this is because of security limitations.

If you could do that, malicious websites can access your browser and tamper with your system.